# How can I get a multiple value from checkbox in custom listview android

Tags: android, checkbox

i want to get multiple value of data from my checkbox
i get my data from mysql database and show the list on alertdialog

how can I get multiple data when checkbox is checked

```
 final ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();

    kList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>>();

    listView = new ListView(this);
            **if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                fas = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(PasangActivity.this,fas,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //selected.add(fas);
            }** I have tried using this but its useless ...................
            Log.e("SELECTED",""+selected);


    new detailFasilitas().execute();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PasangActivity.this);
    builder.setView(null).setMessage(null);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setView(listView);
    dialog = builder.create();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" + listView.getCount() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    dialog.show();
```

and this is my asynctask

```
class detailFasilitas extends AsyncTask<String , String, String >{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(DATA_URL_FASILITAS,"GET",params);
        Log.e("Semua Data Fasilitas:",json.toString());
        try{
            int sukses = json.getInt(TAG_SUKSES);
            if (sukses == 1){
                JSONArray kateg = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                for (int x = 0; x<kateg.length();x++){
                    JSONObject c = kateg.getJSONObject(x);

                    String idfas = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String fas = c.getString(TAG_FASILITAS);

                    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID,idfas);
                    map.put(TAG_FASILITAS,fas);
                    kList.add(map);
                }

                Log.e("hmmmm",""+kList);

            }else{

            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PasangActivity.this,kList,R.layout.list_check,new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_FASILITAS},new int[]{R.id.txtid,R.id.checkBox});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I'm still new with this problem. So please help my problem thanks ...